# Rating displayed on site

Tags: feature-request, users

I am an active player on Lichess. I noticed the feature where they show the real life chess title besides the name. Could this be implemented on Chess Stack Exchange? Or is it just not feasible due to low activity of chess masters as compared to Lichess? Could we have a vote for the same?

Comment: It sounds vaguely infeasible but, of course, I am not a StackExchange insider, so what do I know? If it *were* feasible, the idea sounds to me as though it would substantially benefit the site. It would elevate the site's prestige in the world of chess. In concept, I like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this could be a feature in the "expandable usercard" section of the site. I'm no expert on the coding/work required, but perhaps **we could implement the expandable usercard for users with enough reputation and/or have a verified FIDE title.** This way, a title, once verified, can always be seen.

Not sure how well the verification process would work. Lichess seems to handle large amounts of request fairly well; it might be a good idea to require a user to be a member of Chess.SE for at least 10? 30? days to minimize spam requests.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, having FIDE ids would be a good start for users who wish to disclose their membership.